# SQL injection and JPA

Tags: jpa, sql-injection

I have the following code snippet from my GenericDAOImpl

```
final StringBuffer queryString = new StringBuffer("SELECT o from ");

queryString.append(type.getSimpleName()).append(" o ");
queryString.append(this.getQueryClauses(params, orderParams));
final Query query = em.createQuery(queryString.toString());
```

// createQuery() is a private method which builds the where clause and order by clause from the Map/List

This is one sample query this code  snippet created : “SELECT o from temptable o where type = 'x'”

I am just trying to know whether my code is SQL injection prone. Some of the articles say when inlining user input the code is injection prone. I tried to create some of the injection scenarios and my test user inputs created following queries to test the SQL injection.

```
SELECT o from temptable o  where type = 'x' DROP TABLE temptable
SELECT o from temptable o  where type = 'x'; DROP TABLE temptable
```

In both these cases below exceptions were thrown respectively, so no table drop happened.

```
unexpected token: DROP    
unexpected char: ';'
```

I am using the JPA implementation of Hibernate.

In that case, is this code still injection prone? Am I missing some other test cases?
Or do you think any other JPA implementation will fail to throw the exception in such case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still subject to SQL injection; for example (*):

```
SELECT ac.password FROM AccountInfo ac WHERE ac.userId = 'x';
```

could be switched to

```
SELECT ac.password FROM AccountInfo ac WHERE ac.userId = 'inexistentId' or ac.userType = 'administrator'
```

(*) Yes, storing plain text passwords is also wrong to begin with, it is just an example of sensitive information.

Since you already have all the values stored in lists, changing your code to use `setParameter` is pretty trivial (hint, just name then `:param0`, `:param1`, ... and set them in order), so I do not understand why you would not use it to begin with.

Comment: You are right, I will fix my approach. Thank you very much for the quick response.